# Joomla paid ads component / module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, payment-gateway, ads

I have a joomla site, and i would like to integrate an ads system such that the admin can post the ads without any fee from admin panel.

But the normal users in the site must pay to post an ad.

That is, they would be filling up the information such as name, email, ad description and image in the form, and upon submitting the form, it would connect to a payment gateway such as paypal, and upon successful payment, the ad would be inserted in the database, so that the admin can manipulate it later.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i could find some components and modules that support ads system in joomla, though only few of them support paypal:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/ads-a-affiliates/classified-ads